# Why is append() function changing value of variable in every iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, lru

Here is my code.

```
print("enter string")
s=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
r=s.copy()

n=[' ',' ',' ']
d=[]

def rep(index):
    temp=[]
    for i in range(3):
        if(s[index-i-1] not in temp):
            temp.append(s[index-i-1])
    if(len(temp)!=3):
        temp.append(s[index-4])
    return temp[-1]

for i in range(len(s)):
    if(i<3):
        n[i]=s[i]
        print(s[i])
        print(n)
        d.append(n)
        print(d)
    elif(s[i] in n):
        print(s[i])
        print(n)
        d.append(n)
        print(d)
        continue
    else:
        n[n.index(rep(i))]=s[i]
        print(s[i])
        print(n)
        d.append(n)
        print(d)
print(d)
```

The value of `list n` is changing according to LRU and that list is being appended in the `list d` but the append function is changing the list d in every iteration. Can someone please tell how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are appending `list n` to `list d`, you now have 2 ways to access your list. via your variable (`n`), and via `list d` (`d[index]`). both point to the same list object in memory. so when you change list n in one way (`n[index] = value`), you will see the change also when you look inside `list d`.

To solve it, instead of appending `list n` to `list d`, append a copy of `list n` to `list d`.

Replace all `d.append(n)` with `d.append(n.copy())`.

Comment: This solves the issue though changing list n should not change list d, why is that happening?

Comment: @Athena I've updated my answer with the explanation.